# multiple repository in one controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i have 3 tables
person, address, personaddress
person has id, name
address has id, address
personaddress has personid, addressid
it's a many to many
all of this works fine if i go into person to search by name, delete, update, add. samething with address. However, what i want to do is when i search by name i want to see it pulls not only name but all the addresses that that name associates with and vice versa with address. That is why i have personaddress table as cross reference. So this is where i'm stuck, i'm not sure how to do the join on select because it requires a join on all 3 tables. then the delete require me to delete the xref table and the main table as well. Any help is really appreciated.

so i created person, address, personaddress class in Model folder
person

```
public class Person 
{
    public int Id {}
    public string Name {}
}
```

address

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id {}
    public string Address{}
}
```

personaddress

```
public class PersonAddress 
{
    public int PersonId {}
    public string AddressId {}
}
```

i also created iperson, iaddress, ipersonaddress class in Model folder,
interface IPerson

```
{
    IEnumerable<Person> GetAll();
    Person Get(int id);
    Person Add(Person pers);
    void Remove(int id);
    bool Update(Person pers);        
}
```

interface IAddress

```
{
    IEnumerable<Address> GetAll();
    AddressGet(int id);
    AddressAdd(Address addr);
    void Remove(int id);
    bool Update(Address addr);        
}
```

interface IPersonAddress

```
{
    IEnumerable<PersonAddress> GetAll();
    PersonAddressGet(int id);
    PersonAddressAdd(PersonAddress persaddr);
    void Remove(int id);
    bool Update(PersonAddress persaddr);        
}
```

then i created personrepository, addressrepository, personaddressrepository in model folder

```
public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    private List<Person> people= new List<Person>();
    private int _nextId = 1;

    public PersonRepository()
    {
        Add(new Person{ Name = "Peter Smith" });
        Add(new Person{ Name = "Joe Doe" });
    }

    public IEnumerable<Person> GetAll()
    {
        return people;
    }

    public PersonGet(int id)
    {
        return people.Find(p => p.Id == id);
    }

    public PersonAdd(Person pers)
    {
        if (pers== null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("pers");
        }
        pers.Id = _nextId++;
        people.Add(pers);
        return pers;
    }

    public void Remove(int id)
    {
        people.RemoveAll(m => m.Id == id);
    }

    public bool Update(Person pers)
    {
        if (pers==null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("pers");
        }
        int index = people.FindIndex(p => p.Id == pers.Id);
        if (index ==-1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        people.RemoveAt(index);
        people.Add(pers);
        return true;
    }
}
```

then i added controller for those 3 person, address, personaddress

```
public class PersonController : ApiController
{        
    static readonly IPersonRepository repository = new PersonRepository();
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersonByName(string name)
    {
        return repository.GetAll().Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()));
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage AddPerson(Person pers)
    {
        pers= repository.Add(pers);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Person>(HttpStatusCode.Created, pers);

        string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = pers.Id });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }

    public void UpdatePerson(int id, Person person)
    {
        person.Id = id;
        if (!repository.Update(person))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }

    public void DeletePerson(int id)
    {
        Person pers= repository.Get(id);
        if (pers== null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        repository.Remove(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got several possibilities. Here`s two of them.

1. Add  `public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses{ get; set; }`  to your model class and initalize it inside the `Constructor`: `Addresses = new Collection<Addresses>();` This will enable lazy loading of your related child collection. Do the same for `Address` class.
2. Eager load them with `Include()` in your `Get()` and `GetAll()` methods.

   Example: `context.Persons.Include("Address").Where(x => x.PersonId == Id).ToList();` 
   Or Shape your desired result with Linq

For deleting:

```
    var person = context.Persons.GetById(personId);
    
    foreach(var personAddress in person.Addresses)
    {
        person.Addresses.Remove(personAddress);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Or

```
    var person = context.Persons.GetById(personId);
    person.Addresses.Load();
    person.Addresses.ToList().ForEach(x => context.Addresses.DeleteObject(x));
```

Edit: Sample Person Class

```
public class Person()
{
    public Person()
    {
        Addresses = new Collection<Address>();
    }

    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual Collection<Address> Addresses {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: for step 1 are u saying initalize it in the interface?

Comment: No, in you `Person` class.

Comment: sorr i'm new and trying to learn mvc and c#. lol probably should have picked vb. so it should be in 
[code]
    public class Address
    {
        public int Id {}
        public string Address{}
        public virtual ICollection<Person> People {get;set;}
        public People
        {
             People = new Collection<People>();
        }
[/code]

Comment: its saying it can't find collection in the constructor new collection<Address>();

Comment: never mind on teh collection error. i had to include using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

Comment: step 2 is in the repository right and not the controller?

Comment: for some reason it doesn't see "include" at all. this get is in the PersonRepository. and i declared people as  private List<Person> people= new List<Person>();

public Person Get(int id)
    {
        //return people.Find(p => p.Id == id);
        return people.Include("Addresses").Where(x => x.PersonId == id).ToList()
    }

Comment: I think that you need to `Include("Address")`, not Addresses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72981/discussion-between-user3731575-and-vortex).

Comment: this answer will work great if you have model ado.net data entity model. for my example it strictly just working on memory. Thanks for all your help vortex